# CSS Grid — If wrapped, divide equally across rows

Tags: css, layout, flexbox, css-grid

I'm learning CSS grid.

I have the following set up:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(45px, 1fr));
```

So that if the children would be smaller than 45px, wrap instead.

I'm wondering though if it's possible to have it so that if there's any wrapping, to divide the children equally across the 'rows' that are formed instead.

For example, given 12 children, it's either 1 row of 12, 2 rows of 6, 3 rows of 4, etc.

Comment: No, this is not possible dynaically with CSS-Grid or any other layout method. AFAIK

Comment: It's possible with media queries.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
.parent-class { 
    display:grid; 
    grid-template-columns:repeat(4, 1fr); /* repeat 4 columns per row */
    grid-template-columns:repeat(6, 1fr); /* repeat 6 columns per row */
    column-gap:15px;
}
```